# Qt class for handling file paths

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt equivalent of PathAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014145/qt-equivalent-of-pathappend)

Is there a class that handles file paths in Qt? Particularly I'm looking for something like .NET's Path.Combine.

I know there's one in boost::filesystem but I was wondering if there's one in Qt.

Comment: An answer in [Qt equivalent of PathAppend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014145/qt-equivalent-of-pathappend)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [QDir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html) which might be of help (see `QDir::relativeFilePath` and `QDir::canonicalPath` and others).

Quoting from QDir doc:

> A QDir is used to manipulate path
>   names, access information regarding
>   paths and files, and manipulate the
>   underlying file system.

Comment: Actually QDir is relatively stupid class. For example, it doesn't allow to cd() to nonexisting dir.

Comment: this a joke right ? No program can cd into non existing dir. QDir and QFile are very flexible, I highly recommend it.

Comment: What Sergei meant was `QDir::cd()` which is (should be) just a shortcut  for `return QDir( this->filePath( arg ) )`. This has nothing to do with changing the CWD of the process. If `QDir::cd()` would allow non-existing names, then that would make it _the_ Qt class for abstracting away a Path (currently, `QString` serves that purpose - not!). Like it is now, if Sergei is right, it fails to meet up to the potential, which _indeed_ is a sad design mistake.

Answer (score 9):

Another class that might be useful is `QFileInfo`.

From Qt documentation:

> The QFileInfo class provides
>   system-independent file information.
>
> QFileInfo provides information about a
>   file's name and position (path) in the
>   file system, its access rights and
>   whether it is a directory or symbolic
>   link, etc. The file's size and last
>   modified/read times are also
>   available. QFileInfo can also be used
>   to obtain information about a Qt
>   resource.

Answer (score 3):

QDir provides access to directory contents and allows various manipulation (mkdir for example). But there are no classes for path components manipulation unfortunately.