# os.path.join() in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, path, filenames

I'm looking for an easy, cross platform way to join path, directory and file names into a complete path in C++. I know python has `os.path.join()` and matlab has `fullfile()`. Does Qt has something similar? `QFileInfo` doesn't seem to be able to do this.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740423/qt-class-for-handling-file-paths

Answer (score 14):

[QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdir.html) has `absoluteFilePath` and `relativeFilePath` to combine a path with a file name.

Answer (score 3):

Offhand, I'm not sure about Qt, but Boost has a `filesystem` class that handles things like this. This has the advantage that it has been accepted as a proposal for TR2. That means it has a pretty good chance of becoming part of the C++ standard library (though probably with some minor modifications here or there).