# Is there QPath::Combine in QT4?

Tags: c++, qt, path, qt4, path-separator

I need a similar to .NET method for safely combining path parts without worrying for platform specifics of the path separator.

Is there such class and method in QT4?

Something like:

```
QPath::Combine
```

Comment: please change the accepted answer (see comment about `cd()` performing an existence check)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is not any function that can be used as direct replacement for `Path.Combine()` so you have to write it by your own.

You may do it in the hard way (handling everything by yourself) or simply use `QDir::cleanPath()`:

```
QString pathAppend(const QString& path1, const QString& path2)
{
    return QDir::cleanPath(path1 + QDir::separator() + path2);
}
```

I used `QDir::separator()` but as pointed out in [Cross-platform way of constructing a FS path with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194868/1207195) you do not really need it and you simply can use the <kbd>/</kbd>. `QDir::cleanPath()` will remove double <kbd>/</kbd> (or double <kbd>\</kbd>, according to `QDir::separator()`) and will resolve <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>..</kbd> to appropriate values. See also [Qt equivalent of PathAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014145/qt-equivalent-of-pathappend/13014378#13014378) for code about QT `PathAppend()` replacement.

As said it mimics `PathAppend()` native function (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565(v=vs.85).aspx)) but this is **not an exact replacement** of `Path.Combine()` because `Path.Combine()` doesn't perform an *cleaning* or normalization (it just appends strings, handling directory separators in the proper way, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)). If you need an **exact replacement** you may use this one:

```
QString pathCombine(const QString& path1, const QString& path2)
{
    if (path2.startsWith(QDir::separator()))
        return path2;

    return trimEnd(path1, QDir::separator())
        + QDir::separator()
        + trim(path2, QDir::separator());
}
```

This function will not add a trailing directory separator if `path2` is a directory name (it doesn't perform any check and path may even not exist at all). Also note that `path2` must be a sub-path of `path1` (relative paths upper than `path1` aren't supported, if you need them you have to use previous version with `QDir::cleanPath()`), also if `path2` is rooted then `path2` is returned (this implementation is pretty naive, for example it doesn't *detect* `c:\directory` as a rooted path).

`trim()` and `trimEnd()` functions remove trailing directory separator (for a possible, generic, implementation see [How do I remove trailing whitespace from a QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215303/how-do-i-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-a-qstring-in-qt-c) as starting point). *Algorithm* to ensure there is a trailing directory separator is same one described in [How to ensure there is trailing directory separator in paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406065/1207195) (simplified because here we always have one directory separator given by `QDir::separator()`).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the static methods `QDir::fromNativeSeparators` and `QDir::toNativeSeparators` and then use `/` everywhere when manipulating the path.

Comment: This may do the trick but Path.Combine has the trick to also ensure that you have not forgotten the trailing path delimiter when combining

    Path.Combine("c://test_folder", "filename.txt")

Is there such safe path combining technique in QT?

Comment: Have a look at `QDir` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740423/qt-class-for-handling-file-paths .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything exactly like that, but you can get close by using `QDir::cd()`:

```
QDir path("base_path");
path.cd("subdir");
```

Unfortunately, I think that only works for directories, not files.  For files, you could use `QDir::filePath()`:

```
QDir path("base_path");
QString file_path = path.filePath("file.txt");
```

Comment: Note that `cd()` does not really perform path manipulation: it will only perform the cd operation if the source directory exists, so it mixes path construction with check for existence (which is silly IMHO).

Comment: @LucTouraille totally silly!  it's complicating my unit testing