# How do I remove trailing whitespace from a QString?

Tags: c++, string, qt, qt4, trim

I want to remove all the trailing whitespace characters in a `QString`. I am looking to do what the Python function `str.rstrip()` with a `QString`.

I did some Googling, and found this: http://www.qtforum.org/article/20798/how-to-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-qstring.html

So what I have right now is something like this:

```
while(str.endsWith( ' ' )) str.chop(1);
while(str.endsWith( '\n' )) str.chop(1);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I want to keep all the whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: I think the logic it's flawed: should be while(str.endsWith(' ' ) || str.endsWith( '\n' )) str.chop(1);

Comment: @chac, yea it will fail on a string like this: "abc \n \n"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`QString` has two methods related to trimming whitespace:

- [`QString QString::trimmed() const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed)
  Returns a string that has whitespace removed from the start and the end.
- [`QString QString::simplified() const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified)
  Returns a string that has whitespace removed from the start and the end, and that has each sequence of internal whitespace replaced with a single space.

If you want to remove only trailing whitespace, you need to implement that yourself. Here is such an implementation which mimics the implementation of `trimmed`:

```
QString rstrip(const QString& str) {
  int n = str.size() - 1;
  for (; n >= 0; --n) {
    if (!str.at(n).isSpace()) {
      return str.left(n + 1);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use QString::trimmed()

Comment: @nullstellensatz `trimmed` removes leading and trailing whitespace while `rstrip` only removes trailing whitespace.

Comment: Gotta love how Qt offers some really fancy features yet fails at some of the most basic tasks...2017 and this functionality is still missing.

Comment: One person's "basic task" is another person's "why would anyone ever need that?"

Comment: Right trimming is pretty much a standard everywhere in modern languages, though.

Answer (score 31):

[`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) provides only two trimming-related functions. In case if they don't suit your needs, I'm afraid you need to implement your own custom trimming function.

[`QString QString::simplified () const`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified)
Returns a string that has whitespace removed from the start and the end, and that has each sequence of internal whitespace replaced with a single space.

```
QString str = "  lots\t of\nwhitespace\r\n ";
str = str.simplified();
// str == "lots of whitespace";
```

[`QString QString::trimmed () const`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed)
Returns a string that has whitespace removed from the start and the end.

```
QString str = "  lots\t of\nwhitespace\r\n ";
str = str.trimmed();
// str == "lots\t of\nwhitespace"
```

Comment: simplified also combines multiple whitespace INSIDE the string

Comment: Yes. Originally I've posted `simplified` and not `trimmed` because author mentions removing `\n`'s as well. But anyway, I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: There is whitespace at the beginning, and I want to keep that whitespace. I also want to keep the whitespace in the middle. I guess I'll have to write my own trimming function. Thanks!

Comment: In this case I would go with regex'es - easy and elegant. Have a look at *skyhisi* answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have or don't need any whitespace at the beginning either, you could use [`QString QString::trimmed () const`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#trimmed).

This ignores any internal whitespace, which is corrected by the alternative solution provided by Andrejs Cainikovs.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a regexp:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString str("Hello world    ");

    qDebug() << str;

    str.remove(QRegExp("\\s+$"));

    qDebug() << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Whether this would be faster, I'm not sure.

Comment: Simple string operations like indexOf(), left(), strstr() and etc. always faster than regular expressions IMHO.

Comment: It's not an opinion, it's a fact. For a mundane thing like stripping whitespace, using Regex is relatively very complex (but you may sometimes *need* regex of course, for complex situations).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to make a deep copy of the string:

```
QString & rtrim( QString & str ) {
  while( str.size() > 0 && str.at( str.size() - 1 ).isSpace() )
    str.chop( 1 );
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[QString::Trimmed()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#trimmed) removes whitespace from the start and the end - if you are sure there is no whitespace at the start you can use this.

Answer (score 2):

No deep copy and no repeated calls to size/chop:

```
QString & rtrimInPlace (QString &str) {
    for (int n = str.size() - 1; n >= 0; -- n)
        if (!str.at(n).isSpace()) {
            str.truncate(n + 1);
            break;
        }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only built-in-functions are `trimmed()` and `simplified()`. So you will need to trim manually. In that case you should use the `QChar` function `isSpace()` to check if a character is a space character.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the answer posted by Frank S. Thomas:

```
QString rstrip(const QString& str, const char *skip = " \r\n\t") {
  int n = str.size() - 1;
  for (; n >= 0; --n) {
    if (0 == strchr(skip, str.at(n).toAscii()))
      return str.left(n + 1);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a non-space char to the begin of the string, trim it, then remove the char

```
str1=QString("-"+str).trimmed().mid(1);
```