# Qt equivalent of PathAppend?

Tags: c++, qt

[PathAppend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a useful winapi function that lets you append one path to another while taking care of any trailing backslashes (or lack of them).

Meaning that appending `"/dir1"` to `"dir2"`, or `"/dir1"` to `"/dir2"`, or `"/dir1/"` to `"/dir2"` would produce the same (correct) result - `"/dir1/dir2"` (while simply concatening would produce respectively `"/dir1dir2"`, `"/dir1/dir2"`, and `"/dir1//dir2"`).

Is there any Qt function that does a similar thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there QPath::Combine in QT4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541529/is-there-qpathcombine-in-qt4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform way of constructing an FS path with Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194725/cross-platform-way-of-constructing-an-fs-path-with-qt)

Comment: Thanks, but most of the answers on those 2 questions are about using the native separator, which is not what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is not that function but `QDir::cleanPath()` will handle everything you need, you just have to concatenate paths:

```
QString appendPath(const QString& path1, const QString& path2)
{
    return QDir::cleanPath(path1 + QDir::separator() + path2);
}
```

I used `QDir::separator()` instead of raw "/" but it's not mandatory because QT internally translate that separator to the native one (if needed, see [Cross-platform way of constructing an FS path with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194868/1207195)).

Note that (for whom with a .NET background) there is another similar function: `Path.Combine()`, it behaves somehow *similar* to `PathAppend()` but it's different. See [Is there a QPath::Combine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014491/1207195) for a QT *emulation* of its behavior (and for a slightly more detailed outlining of their differences).

Comment: I later realized that all OS-es I know support multiple slashes. So `////usr////bin`, `C:////Program Files`, `C:\\\\\\Program Files`, or even `C:\\\/\//\Program Files` will resolve correctly. So you can just concatenate `path1+"/"+path2` with no fear.

Comment: @sashoalm yes, doubles aren't an issue for most OSes but cleanPath() does much more than that (see also linked post). To mimic PathAppend()  it has *resolve* path. If you need to simply concatenate two *simple* paths as input for a read/write function then you may really go happy with concatenation. If you will use calculated path for something else or relative part is more complex then you'd better normalize/clean it too (honestly also for your own sake when debugging...)